# What is best RDS for magento and how to migrate database

Tags: magento-2.1.7, aws

I've a storefront that run on `c5d.xlarge`. I need to migrate database to `RDS`. It's MySQL database and contains about 600 table.

Uploading csv need some processing like get range for years in following attribute: `2000-2013`.

I've two questions:

1- What are the best instance RDS class for magento database?

2- How to migrate database from EC2 instance to RDS?

> Magento version is 2.1.7

**Update:**
Database size is 1568.22MB which is about 1.6GB and average daily checkouts range from 200 checkout/day up to 200 checkout/day

Comment: what is your database size in GB ? how many checkouts you have daily?

Comment: @MagenX it's 1568.22 MB which is 1.6 GB. minimum checkouts are 200 per day

Comment: with 200 checkouts and ~2Gb of data you probably need to start from ~4Gb RDS instance, but if you check your database for garbage and cleanup logs, even smaller instance.